# Configuring Onsen UI using RequireJS in Cordova app

Tags: cordova, requirejs, onsen-ui

I am new to requireJS and Onsen UI. I am migrating an existing HTML5 app to cordova and it all works well. The existing code uses requireJS to load modules, and now I am trying to add Onsen UI to provide a better mobile UI. I have ran the Onsen UI sample templates and they work perfect however when I try to include Onsen UI module in the existing requireJS configuration the pages do not load properly.

Does anyone has done this configuration before? Or can anyone point me to some documentation? I tried to follow a similar configuration from this project (https://github.com/jrowny/ionic-angular-cordova-require-seed) for ionic + angular + require without any luck.

**This is my index.html**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" />
  <!-- Onsenui CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lib/onsenui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lib/onsen-css-components.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <ons-split-view 
    secondary-page="menu.html" 
    main-page="page1.html" 
    main-page-width="70%" 
    collapse="portrait">
  </ons-split-view>
  <ons-template id="page1.html">
    <ons-page class="center">
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
          <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="ons.splitView.toggle()">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
          </ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">Page 1</div>
      </ons-toolbar>
      <div class="content-padded" style="font-size: 13px; text-align: center; color: #999;">
        <p>Rotate the device to landscape/portrait see the views split/collapse.</p>
        <p>Or resize the window so that the width is larger than the height (landscape)/smaller than the height (portrait).</p> 
      </div>
      <ons-bottom-toolbar>
      </ons-bottom-toolbar>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>
  <ons-template id="page2.html">
    <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">Page 2</div>
      </ons-toolbar>
      <div class="content-padded" style="font-size: 13px; text-align: center; color: #999;">
        <p>Rotate the device to landscape/portrait see the views split/collapse.</p>
        <p>Or resize the window so that the width is larger than the height (landscape)/smaller than the height (portrait).</p> 
      </div>
      <ons-bottom-toolbar>
      </ons-bottom-toolbar>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>
  <ons-template id="menu.html">
    <ons-page modifier="menu-page">
      <ons-toolbar modifier="transparent"></ons-toolbar>
      <ons-list class="menu-list">
        <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="ons.splitView.setMainPage('page1.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="fa-plus"></ons-icon>
          New Post
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="ons.splitView.setMainPage('page2.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="fa-bookmark"></ons-icon>
          Bookmark
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="ons.splitView.setMainPage('page1.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="fa-twitter"></ons-icon>
          Official Twitter
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
      <br>
      <ons-list class="bottom-menu-list">
        <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="ons.splitView.setMainPage('page2.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          Settings
          <div class="notification menu-notification">3</div>
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="ons.splitView.setMainPage('page1.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          Help
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="ons.splitView.setMainPage('page2.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          Send feedback
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>
  <script data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the main.coffee script**

```
require.config 
    paths: 
    cordova: '../cordova'
    backbone: 'lib/backbone-1.1.0'
    jquery: 'lib/jquery-1.9.0.min'
    lodash: 'lib/lodash-2.2.1.min'
    text: 'lib/text'
    marionette: 'lib/marionette.min'
    json2: 'lib/json2'
    vasat: 'lib/vasat'
    onsen: 'lib/onsenui'
    angular: 'lib/angular.min'
  shim:
    jquery:
      exports:'$'
    lodash:
      exports:'_'
    backbone:
      deps:['jquery','lodash']
      exports:'Backbone'
    marionette:
      deps:['backbone']
    vasat:
      deps:['marionette','text','json2']
      exports:'V'
    angular:
      exports:'angular'
    onsen:
      deps:['angular']

require ['onsen']
```

The page loads fine for a second and then I get a blank page and the below error in the javascript console.

```
Error: This function is not registered in the lock list.
at Object.window.DoorLock.DoorLock._unlock (http://localhost:8383/project/js/lib/onsenui.js:4112:15)
at unlock (http://localhost:8383/project/js/lib/onsenui.js:4100:14)
at h.$broadcast (http://localhost:8383/project/js/lib/angular.min.js:104:521)
at link.post (http://localhost:8383/project/js/lib/onsenui.js:9143:24)
at E (http://localhost:8383/project/js/lib/angular.min.js:49:345)
at f (http://localhost:8383/project/js/lib/angular.min.js:42:399)
at f (http://localhost:8383/project/js/lib/angular.min.js:42:416)
at f (http://localhost:8383/project/js/lib/angular.min.js:42:416)
at http://localhost:8383/project/js/lib/angular.min.js:42:67
at http://localhost:8383/project/js/lib/angular.min.js:18:67 angular.min.js:84(anonymous function) angular.min.js:84(anonymous function) 
GET http://localhost:8383/project/page1.html net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE angular.min.js:72
Error: Page is not found: page1.html
```

Any help much appreciated.